# Run CMD as admin in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, cmd

I hope this is simple.

```
$cred = Get-Credential $env:USERDOMAIN\$env:USERNAME
$credUser = $cred.UserName
$credPW = $cred.Password

$Col1Row2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Col1Row2.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(5,80)
$Col1Row2.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,25)
$Col1Row2.Text = "CMD as Admin"
$Col1Row2.Add_Click({Write-Host "Started Command Prompt.";$x= RunAs /user:$credUser C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe })
$objForm.Controls.Add($Col1Row2)
```

There's a button to start command prompt inside my form, but I want it to start as admin by catching the user credentials at the beginning and using them to run.  The problem is I can't seem to figure out how to get this to work.

If I run it in the script, it doesn't seem to work at all (in ISE).  If I run the line in PowerShell as `RunAs /user:$credUser C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe` it asks for the password.  If I run it with the password at the end it doesn't seem to care.  Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`$params=@("/C";"$x";" >d:\temp\result.txt")`

Parameters go here, change it to your parameters that you want to pass to Command Prompt.

Start Process takes Credential Object hence suggesting this approach.

```
$params=@("/C";"$x";" >d:\temp\result.txt")
$prog="cmd.exe"
Start-Process -Credential $cred  -Verb runas $prog +$params
```

Comment: `Start-Process -Credential $cred  -Verb runas cmd.exe` returns `Start-Process : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.`.  Plus I don't have any parameters to run.  I just want to run cmd.exe with the captured user information.

Comment: Tell me what are the things you will be doing when you open command prompt, certain set of codes will be executed right?

Comment: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/132e170f-e3e8-4178-9454-e37bfccd39ea/startprocess-verb-runas-credential?forum=winserverpowershell This may guide you right

Comment: I don't need anything run special.  I just need to run cmd.exe with the privileges captured previously.

Comment: start-process -Credential $cred  'cmd.exe' -noExit

Comment: `start-process -Credential $cred cmd.exe -noExit` yields:  `start-process : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'noExit'`  and `start-process -Credential $cred cmd.exe'` yields:  `start-process : This command cannot be run due to the error: The directory name is invalid.`